# Android reduce animation quality

Tags: android, android-animation

I am using animation to make transition between image views.
The problem is when pictures are in high res the transition animation is slow with lag.
How can i reduce quality before animation and return it to normal. Like in the build in viewer when sliding between images they are in reduced quality.
Here is relevant parts from my code:

```
imageView  = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imv1);
imageView2  = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imv2);

imageView.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeFile("/sdcard/Tablet/fashion1.jpg"));
imageView2.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeFile("/sdcard/Tablet/fashion2.jpg"));

//After button click:
imageView2.startAnimation(anim);
imageView.startAnimation(anim2);
```